# Modify/Truncate the Data picked up by a bar code scanner

Tags: windows-xp, barcode-scanner

I trying to find a solution for a scanning problem I have.  We print packing slips to place with orders we ship via UPS. Currently, users have to type in the patient information.  I would like to use a scanner to ease this process. The packing slips already have bar codes, but here is the problem I have run into:

When the bar code is scanned it returns text like `TOR12345`.  I need it to ignore the letters and only return the numbers.  Is there a way to set the scanner to only accept numbers, or to ignore the first 3 characters?  It seems this should be possible.

We have several models of handheld scanners, but i am doing my testing with a [Honeywell Xenon 1900](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-US/Pages/Product.aspx?category=hand-held-barcode-scanner&cat=HSM&pid=1900).

[image]

Comment: How do you think the behavior can be customized? I see a lot of software tools on their webpage. You think one of those tools can be used? Or is a third-party tool a valid option?

Comment: A third party tool would be great as we have multiple brands of scanners.

Comment: I tied to follow the OCR User's guide but i can't get the scanner to accept any of the settings.  It just gives me a denial beep.